# Log Analyzer Tools for IIS Webserver Logs

Tags: iis, logging, google-analytics

I used  [Deep Log Analyzer](http://www.deep-software.com/) to monitor my site visits. What I noticed now, is that there is way too much traffic reported than it actually should be reported based on google analytics. I started to use GA now but I need to create a clean report from April 2017 until November 2017 based on the iis logs.

I got all of the log files from IIS. But now I'm looking for a way to filter spam like /wp-admin Brute-Force stuff and to monitor just the 'real' visitors data without bots and internal refferers.

Is there any better tool for that kind of log reporting or is there a way to achieve that goal in Deep Log Analyzer?

I tried to filter the reports but It still seems to have too much hits.

I just need the following information:

> Total Visits, Amount of users, average session time, and device (if mobile or desktop)

thanks for recommendations and help

**EDIT:** best solution I found: http://www.weblogexpert.com/

Comment: If you found the answer, post it below and accept it. In general tool recommendation is off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

I would look at Log Parser Studio: 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2012/03/07/introducing-log-parser-studio/

It allows SQL like log querying and filtering.

**Edit**:
Possible new link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/log-parser-studio-2-0-is-now-available/ba-p/593266

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I struggled to find the download link so sharing for anyone interested:
1 - Download and install the Log Parser (CLI) from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24659
2 - Download and run the Log Parser Studio (UI) executable from here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/introducing-log-parser-studio/ba-p/601131  (LPSV2.D2.zip) Edit: Log Parser Studio requires Log Parser.

Answer (score 5):

I realize Im a bit late to the party but, having tried a bunch of freeware tools out there I can say with certainty that **HttpLogBrowser** (https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2017/04/httplogbrowser) is the best of the bunch

- Really quick to load up one or more log files for analysis
- Not sluggish when browsing/searching/filtering the data (despite using very little memory)
- Extremely useful visual representations of logged data

Answer (score -2):

You could do this with the free edition of [SpectX](https://www.spectx.com). Download and point it to your IIS log folder. Tutorials and sample queries:

[Parsing IIS logs](https://www.spectx.com/articles/parsing-iis-logs)

[Analyzing IIS Logs](https://www.spectx.com/articles/analyzing-iis-logs)

[Analyzing IIS logs: Microsoft Exchange, OWA and ActiveSync Activities](https://www.spectx.com/articles/parse-iis-logs-to-analyze-exchange-outlook-web-access-and-activesync-activities)

A very basic way of filtering out bots is to configure [SpectX to access Maxmind's GeoIP databases](https://docs.spectx.com/v2/spectx_core/getting_started/installing_desktop/maxmind_config.html#configure-downloading-maxmind-databases) and then use the filter_out command. For example:

```
| filter_out(asname(c_ip) = ‘AS15169 Google LLC’ and cs_user_agent like ‘%Googlebot/%‘)
| filter_out(asname(c_ip) = ‘AS8075 Microsoft Corporation’ and cs_user_agent like ‘%BingPreview/%‘)
| filter_out(asname(c_ip) = ‘AS8075 Microsoft Corporation’ and cs_user_agent like ‘%bingbot/%‘)
| filter_out(asname(c_ip) = ‘AS32934 Facebook, Inc.’ and cs_user_agent like ‘%facebookexternalhi%‘)
| filter_out(asname(c_ip) = ‘AS14618 Amazon.com, Inc.’ and cs_user_agent like ‘%SMTBot/%‘)
| filter_out(asname(c_ip) = ‘AS714 Apple Inc.’ and cs_user_agent like ‘%Applebot/%‘)
| filter_out(asname(c_ip) = ‘AS13238 YANDEX LLC’ and cs_user_agent like ‘%YandexBot/%‘)
| filter_out(asname(c_ip) = ‘AS13238 YANDEX LLC’ and cs_user_agent like ‘%YandexMobileBot/%’)
```